# Paypal API List Withdraws

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal

I'm implementing a PHP Web application that uses PayPal for payments. I'm using for all the things the REST API.
My problem is how can I get the list of withdraws from PayPal API?

I'm going to use the functionality to withdraw to a bank every day, but I will need to see, with the API, those withdraws...

Any idea? I'm a little bit lost after spending two days searching and trying page on google.

Thank you in advance,
Rui

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the REST API supports it yet.  The Classic API does, though, with the [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) API.

Our [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make this very quick and easy for you to setup.